# using useRef Hook "element.current" is null inside useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [data, setData] = useState<string>('');

let element = useRef(null);
let editor = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    //fetch
    setData(fetchResult);
});

useEffect(() => {
    //element.current always is null
    if (element.current !== null) {
     editor.current = new JSONEditor(element.current, someOptions);
    }
}, [data, element]);

return (
<div>
        {loading && <CircularIndeterminateLoading />}
        {!loading && <div ref={element}></div>}
</div>)
```

element can be not null, but property .current is always null

any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Had you set `ref` to any element?

Comment: @Asifvora updated question with return

Comment: It should be`element.current` instead of `editor.current`

Comment: You probably should add `loading` as a dependency in your `useEffect`

Comment: @PsyGik thx for your proposal, yeah by adding loading as dependency in second useEffect solved the issue, can you add as an answer and I will accept it, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should add `loading` as a dependency in your `useEffect` because your `ref` is assigned only when the `div` is rendered, which in turn depends on the `loading` value.

By adding `loading` to the `useEffect` dependency, the `ref` will be available when the `loading` value changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (element.current !== null) {
    editor.current = new JSONEditor(element.current, someOptions);
  }
}, [data, element, loading]);

return (
  <div>
    {loading && <CircularIndeterminateLoading />}
    {!loading && <div ref={element}></div>}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: In real-time usage, you can't trust that `loading` value change will indeed trigger the effect before re-paint had covered up

Answer (score 0):

You might use an isolated recursive function for making sure that there's some value under the ref

```
let handleEditor = () => element.current !== null ?
             editor.current = new JSONEditor(element.current, someOptions)
             : setTimeout(handleEditor, 50)

useEffect(() => {
    handleEditor()    
}, [data, element]);
```